# How do you kill the thunar process?

Tags: linux, unix, thunar

If I'd like to kill all instances of that file manager, I'd do

```
killall thunar
```

which gives me

```
thunar: no process found
```

But this FM is definitely running!

[image: Screenshot of an active thunar window]

---

Similarly `ps aux | grep thunar` doesn't find anything and yields:

```
cadoiz      27791  0.0  0.0   9588  2656 pts/0    S+   11:33   0:00 grep --color=auto thunar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`killall` seems to be case sensitive and for some reason, `Thunar` with capital `T` works:

```
killall Thunar
```

You can consider [this debian forum](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=146564) discussing the topic.